# MongoDB - how do i see everything in a collection using the shell?

Tags: mongodb

I deployed a test app (http://meteortipslinda2.meteor.com/) and added accounts-facebook. Facebook login does not work, however, because I probably input the wrong API key.

I know I can access the shell with `meteor mongo meteortipslinda2.meteor.com`, but I'm at a loss about how to see everything in these collections:

meteor_accounts_loginServiceConfiguration
meteor_oauth_pendingCredentials
meteor_oauth_pendingRequestTokens

I'm assuming that I can update the value to the correct one in the mongoDB shell, but first I need to figure out how to see the contents of the collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To list all the documents in a collection, just call find without any parameters.

`db.myCollection.find()`

If there are a lot of documents, it will batch them up. You will then be able to show the next batch by typing `it`.